# typescript - How can I retyping a interface from dependence

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

It's hard to describe so I create a repo: https://github.com/galenyuan/how-to-retyping

I want to do like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

declare module 'vuex/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $store: number
  }
}
```

which Vue is defined in `vue/types/vue` and vuex retyping it in `vuex/types/vue`, so how can I custom it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, all module augmentations have to target the actual module that declares what is being augmented. This can be observed in the `vuex` augmentation itself.

```
// vuex/types/vue.d.ts
declare module "vue/types/vue" {
  interface Vue {
    $store: Store<any>;
  }
}
```

You need to do the same. That is, in your `types/store.d.ts` you would write

```
export {} // ensure this file is a module

declare module "vue/types/vue" {
  interface Vue {
    $store: Store<any>;
  }
}
```

That will work, which is to say that it will be seen as an augmentation of `Vue`. Unfortunately we will immediately hit another error, one for which do not know of a workaround.

> Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '$store' has type 'Store' at `*****/how-to-retyping-master/node_modules/vuex/types/vue.d.ts 15:4, but here has type 'number'.

This is a limitation of declaration merging, overlapping member declarations conflict.

There is not a good way around this because importing `"vuex"` prevents us from excluding anything it imports, and that means we cannot exclude the augmentation that ships with it.

We could redirect our import of `"vuex"` using paths, or shadow it with an ambient external module declaration, but that would require us to redeclare everything in `"vuex/types/index.d.ts"` and `"vuex/types/helpers.d.ts"` which is not practical or maintainable.

Comment: Thans for your answer, so it means I can not change it to a number or any other type？

Comment: Unfortunately not. I tried excluding or hiding `vuex/types/vue.d.ts` in various ways, remapping it, but the problem is that it is imported by `vuex/types/index.d.ts` and we need that file.